# Java: variable length parameters as list for recursion

Tags: java, arrays, list, recursion, parameters

I would something like the following recursive method:

```
private Node getElementRec(Node currentNode, String ... names) {
    if (null == names || names.length == 0)
        return currentNode;
    else {
        Node child = currentNode.getChildWithName(names[0]);
        return getElementRec(child, namesAux.subList(1, names[1,]));
    }
}
```

Since variable length Java parameters (here `names`) are arrays, I cannot make something like `names.sublist(1, names.size())` Although it would be rather inefficient, I've tried to convert the array to a list and then pass it to the method, but it doesn't accept a list

**So the question is**: is it possible in Java to do recursion over a variable length parameter `(Type ... parameter)`? Something like I showed is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I wrote in the first sentence 'vectors' when I meant 'arrays'. I don't need the replies answering that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the index

```
private Node getElementRec(Node currentNode, int i, String ... names) {
    if (null == names || names.length == i)
        return currentNode;
    else {
        Node child = currentNode.getChildWithName(names[i]);
        return getElementRec(child, i+1, names);
    }
}
```

Comment: As simply as that, that's Java's way. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the copyOfRange function from the Arrays class to pass to the function

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(names, 1, names.length)
```

Another way to avoid copying would be to modify your function to accept start and end index:

```
private Node getElementRec(Node currentNode, int start, int end, String ... names) {
    if (null == names || start >= end || start < 0 || end > names.length)
        return currentNode;
    else {
        Node child = currentNode.getChildWithName(names[start]);
        return getElementRec(child, start+1, end, names);
    }
}
```

Comment: copyOfRange is the most concise way to recurse with varargs, but +1 for supplying the copy-free alternative!  Nice.  I think the OP is looking for conciseness here, given the mention that recursion isn't the most efficient approach.

Comment: @fiver I don't need the `start` & `end` checks, however you give the solution, like @irreputable, that the efficient way is just to pass the index, and you mention copyOfRange that I didn't know. Nevertheles, the security checks should return something like null, and start should be compared with the length.

Comment: I make sure start < end and end <= length. So no need for comparing start with length...

Comment: Of course, but I need just one index and just one comparison. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `names.size()` you can use `names.length`
Varags `...` in java are arrays, not vectors as you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

`String ... names` is a shorthand of `String[] names`.
So you can try:

```
else {
     Node child = currentNode.getChildWithName(names[0]);
     String[] remainingNames = new String[names.length -1];
     System.arrayCopy(names, 1, remainingNames, 0, names.length - 1);
     return getElementRec(child, remainingNames));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array in place of vararg:

```
private Node getElementRec(Node currentNode, String ... names) {
     String slice[] = ..... // Get sub array from names
     ....
     getElementRec(node, slice);
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off: variable arity parameters are implemented using arrays and not as vectors (vector usually means `java.util.Vector` in Java, which would be a `List` implementation which would have a `subList()` method).

As you realized, collections (specifically `List` objects) allow much richer interactions than simple arrays. Luckily there's an easy way to transform an array into a `List` using [`Arrays.asList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

I'd implement the recursive method using `List<String>` instead of `String...` *and* provide a convenience method that takes a variable arity parameter:

```
private Node getElementRec(Node currentNode, String... names) {
    return getElementRec(currentNode, Arrays.asList(names));
}

private Node getElementRec(Node currentNode, List<String> names) {
    if (null == names || names.isEmpty())
        return currentNode;
    else {
        Node child = currentNode.getChildWithName(names.get(0));
        return getElementRec(child, names.subList(1, names.length()-1));
    }
}
```